# asyncores's handle_close keeps firing continuously

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

self.handlers.append(ConnHandler(sock, self.handlers))I'm new to python and I tried to write a simple socket server to test stuff out and get to know the language better.

```
import asyncore
import socket
import json

class ConnHandler(asyncore.dispatcher_with_send):

    def __init__(self, conn, handlerlist):
        asyncore.dispatcher_with_send.__init__(self, conn)
        self.handlers = handlerlist

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
        print 'Socket closed'
        if(self.handlers.count(self) > 0):
            self.handlers.remove(self);

    def handle_read(self):
        data = ''
        more = True
        while more:
            try:
                data += self.recv(1024)
            except socket.error, e:
                more = False

        if data == '':
            return

        try:
            message = json.loads(data)
        except ValueError:
            self.send('Invalid JSON\n')
            return

        print message


class TestServer(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((host, port))
        self.listen(5)
        self.handlers = []

    def handle_accept(self):
        pair = self.accept()
        if pair is not None:
            sock, addr = pair
            print 'Incoming connection from %s' % repr(addr)
            self.handlers.append(ConnHandler(sock, self.handlers))

    def sendToAll(self, string):
        for h in self.handlers:
            h.send(string + '\n')

server = TestServer('localhost', 55555)
asyncore.loop()
```

My problem is the following.
If I connect to the server with telnet and then quit telnet to close the connection, python just spams 'Socket closed' in the terminal. How can I fix this? Are there obvious beginner mistakes in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

`handle_close` is not meant to detect if peer is disconnected, you get this information in `handle_read` if `.recv` call returns an empty string. Then you can close the socket, and then `handle_close` is called.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
def handle_close(self):
    print 'Socket closed'
    if(self.handlers.count(self) > 0):
        self.handlers.remove(self);

def handle_read(self):
    data = ''
    more = True
    while more:
        try:
            new_data = self.recv(1024)
            if not new_data:
                self.close()
                return
            else:
                data += new_data
        except socket.error, e:
            more = False

    if data == '':
        return

    try:
        message = json.loads(data)
    except ValueError:
        self.send('Invalid JSON\n')
        return

    print message
```